# c++ floating point problems

Tags: c++, g++, floating-point-precision

I'm new to C++ and programming in general . I'm trying out small programs just to get my hand dirty . Below is a program I created for calculating the volume of a cone.

**Problem : No matter what I do the output is always an integer** . I want to get it to two decimal points accuracy . I've tried changing the variables to double and long double to get higher precision and nothing works.

**How can I fix this? And why is this happening ? (In detail if possible)** I've even asked few junior lecturers at UNi so far no one gave me a proper answer.

```
int main (){ 
    float radius,length,volume ;
    const float PI =22/7.0f;
    cin >> radius >> length;
    volume =1/3.0f *radius*radius*length;
    cout << "Volume is " << volume <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using g++ on Fedora

EDIT : I Tried this earlyer with inputs like 50 60/70 50 /120 40 which gives integers. Smaller inputs like 3 4 gives decimals.

EDIT : setprecision() works. thanks for everyone for sent this

Comment: That code prints lots of decimals. (And that approximation for PI is pretty weak.)

Comment: OMG, IT'S TRUE O.O

http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Object-Test,-a-New-PI,-and-More-SHEEIT.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program as posted above (adding the missing `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;`) produces several digits after the decimal point for me. If you want it to produce exactly two decimal after the decimal point you need to use something like this:

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2);
```

somewhere prior to your output (the latter manipulator is declared in `<iomanip>`). The default precision is to use 6 digits and decide how to best distribute them (this may mean the output goes to scientific notation if the values become too big or too small).

BTW, don't use `std::endl` unless you really want to flush your output stream. I found several cases where the inappropriate use of `std::endl` turned into a major performance issue.

Answer (score 4):

You may need to use output manipulators:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setprecision/

so that it looks like:

```
cout << "Volume is " << setprecision(10) << volume << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong with your code, and I cannot reproduce the behaviour you're reporting.

Having said that, if I were you I'd experiment with [`setprecision()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setprecision/):

```
cout << "Volume is " << setprecision(8) << volume <<endl;
```